# Kafka consumer - Reading message header before deserializing

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Is there any way to read message headers before deserializing?

I have written the below code, but I am forced to deserializing here, any way to not deserialize?

```
    while (true) {

        ConsumerRecords<String, String> consumerRecords = consumer.poll(Duration.ofSeconds(1));
        for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> consumerRecord : consumerRecords) {
            for (Header header : consumerRecord.headers()) {
                if (header.key().equals("my header")) {
                    String data = "\n New record received .. \n" +
                            " Value: " + consumerRecord.value() +
                            " Topic: " + consumerRecord.topic() +
                            " Header: " + header.key() +
                            " Partition: " + consumerRecord.partition();

                    logger.info(data);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to write your own Deserializer implementation to be able to access headers before the data payload

Or...

> any way to not deserialize

Set deserializer class to the ByteArrayDeserializer rather than the StringDeserializer.

Then, do the deserialization manually,

```
for (ConsumerRecord<byte[], byte[]> consumerRecord : consumer.poll(Duration.ofSeconds(1))) {
    for (Header header : consumerRecord.headers()) {
       ...

    }
    String s = new String(consumerRecord.value(), "UTF-8"); // for example
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For the C# developers using the Confluent.Kafka library I pushed this solution from the context object:

```
public class KafkaByteDeserializer : IDeserializer<byte[]>
{
        public static KafkaByteDeserializer Instance => new KafkaByteDeserializer();

        public byte[] Deserialize(ReadOnlySpan<byte> data, bool isNull, SerializationContext context)
        {
            if (isNull || IsDeleteOperation(context.Headers))
            {
                return default;
            }

            return data.ToArray();
        }

        private bool IsDeleteOperation(Headers headers)
        {
            // Your logic checking for the delete operation...
        }
}
```